# Return reference

Tags: c++, c++11

1. My expected output of the following code is "1  **-1**  3  4  5  6".
   (`arr[1]=2` should change to `arr[1]=-1`). When I run this code,
   nothing changes, and I can't understand why.
2. What would be the difference if parameter "seek" will be received by "find" function by value and not by reference?
   When I declare that "seek" is a value, the program not running (0xC0000005)... but why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>

int& find (int arr[], int size, int& seek)
{
    for (int i; i<size; i++) {
        if (arr[i]==seek) return arr[i];
    }
    return seek;
}

void print (int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main ()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int size = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    int seek=2;

    find (arr, size, seek) = -1;

    print(arr, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you pass the argument `seek` by value, it's a local variable inside the `find` function. A local variable whose life-time is only inside the function, and will go out of scope once the function returns. References to that variable will be invalid.

Comment: Check the for loop again. `for (int i; i<size; i++) {`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i; i<size; i++) {
```

You need to initialise `i` here

```
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
```

As for the second part - see @Some programmer dude's comment

Comment: It's easy to fail to get warnings for this. GCC (version 8.0.1) with `-Wall -Wextra` will only emit a warning when used with `-O1` or higher.